# Is there a simple way to colorize backup (~) files in bash?

Tags: colors, bash

I'm modifying my terminal color scheme, and I'd like to have the auto-generated backup files (the ones that end with a tilde `~`) be a different color than normal files. Preferably, it would be something I could just stick in my `.dircolors` or `.bashrc`. Is there a keyword or selector for that kind of file? I know you can colorize different file extensions simply by using the extension as a keyword, but I can't find anything that works for a `~`.

Comment: Does putting `~` in `.dircolors` as an extension to match not work?

Comment: Hm, apparently it doesn't. It needs a leading `.` it seems (at least here on CentOS 5).

Comment: Manually adding the pattern to `LS_COLORS` seems to work though.

Comment: Etan: Yeah, I tried that. Unfortunately, that was a no-go. I also tried using "tilde" as a keyword, but that obviously didn't work.

Comment: That's the environment variable that `ls` actually uses. `echo "$LS_COLORS"`.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors suggests e.g. `*~ 01;36` should work.

Comment: (Also, `man dir_colors` indicates that the `.extension` form is considered obsolete, precisely because it doesn't allow you to color files ending extensions like `~` that don't start with a period.)

Comment: I guess that should probably be the official answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to put the pattern `*~` in as a keyword. I probably should have tried that in the first place, but there you go. Thanks to @chepner for the simple answer, and @Etan Reisner for finding another cool way to do it (modifying the `LS_COLORS` variable).